# How could I adjust file tab bar to top of editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

As the screenshot shows, somehow the files-tab and preview (in green rectangle) appeared on the right side; I tried to move or drag it, didn't work though. How could I move it back to top?

Comment: Go to menu Window -> Restore Layout
Or simply press Shift + F7 key.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your layout in Android Studio by selecting "Restore Default layout" in the Window option.

Window -> Restore Default Layout

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints. "Restore default layout" doesn't work but tab placement in editor tabs does.